# Android Studio: how to create a view that stays locked in position even if you scroll within the application?

Tags: android, kotlin, layout

Sort of like how a header stays in place even if you have a recyclerview and scroll down.

Comment: This question is a little vague. Are you saying you want to create some kind of add-on for Android studio or are you asking how to create a view that doesn't scroll within an Android application? If it's the latter then I'd be happy to provide some kind of example, if it's the former then I have no idea how to help

Comment: I think you want a recyclerView with Sticky Headers. if so, you can search for it, there are plenty of examples on web.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ConstrainLayout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:text="LONG LONG LONG LONG LONG LONG LONG LONG LONG LONG LONG LONG LONG LONG LONG LONG TEXT"
            android:textSize="70sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </ScrollView>

    <!--This Button will stay in the same place-->
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```